# Determining Clojure Jar Path

Tags: clojure, leiningen

The point of this question is to clear up confusion about Clojure project.clj dependencies and how to specify a local dependency.

I have a bunch of Clojure lein projects in a tree

```
./projects/clojure/bene-csv # A csv parsing library
./projects/clojure/bene-cmp # A main program that depends on bene-csv
```

I'm editing bene-cmp's project.clj file. I want to make a dependency to 
./projects/clojure/bene-csv/bene-csv-1.0.0-SN.jar .

Do I use simple directory notation to specify the path or something else

Thank you.

### Edit:

I can include bene-csv in my project by entering lein install in the bene-csv project directory, and using these project.clj entries in bene-cmp's project directory's project.clj file:

```
(defproject bene-cmp "1.0.0-SN"
  :description "This is the main benetrak/GIC comparison program."
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.3.2"]
                 [bene-csv "1.0.0-SN"]])
```

However, I am still trying to figure out what the path is, and would appreciate any pointers or help along those lines. Thank You.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Leinigen uses maven dependency management under the covers, so all dependencies get installed in

```
${HOME}/.m2/repository/${groupId-as-path}/${artifactId}/$[version}/${artifactId}-${version}.jar
```

where for `[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]` groupId is `org.clojure`, artifactId is `clojure` and version is `1.3.0`. groupIds are converted to paths, so a groupId of `org.clojure` has a path of `org/clojure`.

In a maven dependency, specified in pom.xml,  this would look like:

```xml
<project>

    ...    

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
           <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.0</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    ...

</project>
```

*Note - If no groupId is specified then leiningen uses same value for both the groupId and artifactId.*

The benefit of using maven dependency management is that it handles transitive dependencies for you, ie. if you specify a dependency on something, you get all the things it depends on and all the thing that those things depend on etc etc.

So to depend on a local project, the correct thing is to install the local project in your local repository.

To save you changing your versions endlessly while in a development phase, maven supports SNAPSHOT dependencies, whereby some extra information is appended to the version (the datetime basically) and maven knows, that for say 1.3.1-SNAPSHOT it should look for the latest version of that snapshot. This is triggered by the naming convention of {version}-SNAPSHOT.

You can, in maven, specify system dependencies with a hard coded path but generally that's bad practice - it's usually used for things that are platform dependent, i.e. may have a native library component.

By default maven central repository is searched, and leinigen adds in [the clojars repository](http://clojars.org/), which serves as a central repo for clojure jars.

leinigen uses this stuff under the covers and builds a classpath referring to the jars in your local maven repository.

Note that you can generate a `pom.xml` from a leinigen project with `lein pom`. You could then drive maven from that. A useful feature is

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

which gives an ascii art represenation of all the dependencies.